# How do i change commit username in github?

Tags: git, github

I am using VS Code and git SCM for committing on Github. I have changed the username and email using the below commands.

```
$ git config --global user.name "DK-shanto"
$ git config --global user.email "shanto**@gmail.com"
```

After pushing, it is not showing the username I used rather it showed my actual name(Dabashis Kundu Shento) two times.

[showing "Dabashis kundu shento" two times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubphO.png)

I have checked if my username and email are correct or not using
`git config --global --edit`
command, and it shows the correct username and email.

[Username and email are correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwEai.png)

I want DK-Shanto as my username. How do I change this username?

Comment: Did you check .git/config?

Comment: The values in `git config` are used to create the commits themselves. Your first screenshot uses a name associated with your GitHub account itself.

Comment: No. After seeing your comment I did but it showed permission denied! -@DonBranson

Comment: Yes, it is my full name in Github. how can I change it? @chepner

Comment: Well, go in GitHub settings

Comment: And to confirm the author assigned to your commits, run `git log --graph --pretty="%h %d %an %ae" `.

Comment: Thanks guys, problem solved.